# Origin City parameter

Tags: sabre

We are trying implement Sabre API for our mobile app development.  Which of the API package from Dev Studio that could use in order to get Origin city parameter for One Way trip search box.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can reference some of the Utility APIs

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_apis/utility